# Export IPA error on Xcode 7 in El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ad-hoc-distribution, app-distribution

Since Xcode 7 and El Capitan I can't export an archive into an IPA file. When I finish the flow `Export... > Save for Ad Hoc Deployment > Export (button)` it displays the following error: `Coulnd't find any platforms at all in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms`

[image]

EDIT:

This would be the relevant part of the logs

In IDEDistribution.standard.log

```
{
  code = 2109;
  description = "couldn't find any platforms at all in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms";
  info =             {
  };
  level = ERROR;
}
```

In IDEDistribution.critical.log

```
2015-10-06 06:50:04 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "couldn't find any platforms at all in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=couldn't find any platforms at all in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms}
```

EDIT 2:

Listing `Platforms` directory:

```
$ ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306  2 oct 10:12 MacOSX.platform
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  wheel  272  2 oct 10:12 WatchOS.platform
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  204  2 oct 10:13 WatchSimulator.platform
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel  272  2 oct 10:13 iPhoneOS.platform
drwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel  170  2 oct 10:14 iPhoneSimulator.platform
```

Comment: make sure that you add appID and added Distribution Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Can you please also  post the log from show logs button?

Comment: have u checked whether developer account is set proper or not in keychain.

Comment: Start *Terminal.app* and update your question with the output from `ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

deselect "Export from bitcode" checkbox in dialog when exporting IPA. If checked it means that you want to test a build created from bitcode. See more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/ExportingYouriOSApp.html)

Comment: Oh god @protspace. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the deployment target .
Clean the project
Build the project & then archive it . You will get it.

Comment: Did you have the same problem I'm having?

Comment: No problem i exported ipa to my desktop

Answer (score 1):

Also you can remove this error by following below steps:

1) Go to Targets

2) Build settings > Set NO to "Enable Bitcode"

3) Try Archive again.